# On WordPress site, the domain name is changed to the IP address if any link is clicked

Tags: domains, wordpress, ip-address

I have registered my domain from namecheap.com 
There I set up an A record type www pointing to my static IP address.
If I enter my domain name in the browser address bar then the the welcome page is shown from my server, unfortunately if I click any link from my welcome page then the domain name changes to the static IP address/{link_name}

Example:
I type in the web browser address bar: `www.example.com` => my welcome page is shown. if I click on post1 from my welcome page then I would like to address in the browser to change to `www.example.com/post1`.
Instead the address is changed to `44.21.11.22/post1` (the ip address of the server).

I am running a WordPress site and my server is a QNAP NAS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WordPress, this usually means that you have the "site address" setting set to your IP address.   From the [WordPress documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL):

> On the Settings->General screen in a single site installation of WordPress, there are two fields named "WordPress Address (URL)" and "Site Address (URL)". They are important settings, since they control where WordPress thinks your site is located. They control the display of the URL in the admin section of your page, as well as the front end, and are used throughout the WordPress code.
>
> The "Site Address (URL)" setting is the address you want people to type in their browser to reach your WordPress blog.

Go into your WordPress admin section, find that setting and change it to your domain name.